# Django MSSQL server on docker container won't migrate

Tags: python, django, docker, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

> UPDATE: Solved

I am using macOS, Django 2.0 on a virtualenv, and a Docker Container with the SQL Server 2017 up and running. I'm trying to use this package: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

This is my DATABASES settings.py setup:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'TUTORIAS_DATOS',
        'HOST': '0.0.0.0',
        'PORT': '1402',
        'USER': '***',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'driver_charset': 'iso-8859-1',
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` the migration is made, but when I try to apply the migration to the database (`python manage.py migrate`) I get:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, menu, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Instead of what I should get if I use the sqlite (default Django database), which is:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, menu, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying menu.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

I don't know what could be the problem, theoretically if I follow this steps (on Windows) it works just fine.

The ODBC connection apparently is working because if I setup an improper username/password I get an error. My database (of the container hosted on 0.0.0.0:1402) name is indeed TUTORIAS_DATOS

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to Database. Can you try migrating app by app?

like `./manage.py makemigrations appname` and `./manage.py migrate appname`

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting the same response, it makes the migration but doesn't apply it.

Comment: Are you running those migrations inside the docker container?

Comment: Can you make sure that the application is connected to docker database? :)

Comment: @ruddra as explained before I think it detects the connection, because if I set up wrongly the password I get an error (of wrong session init) and if I set it up correctly then no error is returned

Comment: @RobertMoskal how could I do that? I'm running the migrations on the venv

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake. Try the localhost for the database.  Or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: I was using TeamSQL app to "see" the tables on the database and make queries. Little I knew the app didn't work properly.. I've connected to the container and queried via `sqlcmd` and the tables were there... That's why I wasn't getting any "creation" response from Django.

Issue solved, thanks anyways for the comments.